# Dynamic arguments and return type

Tags: c#, dynamic

Apologies if this is blindingly obvious but I can't work it out or string together the right search terms to find the answer I'm looking for.

Consider the following code:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Query<T>(string command, dynamic param = null)
{
  return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
}

public T FirstOrDefault<T>(string command, dynamic param = null)
{
  return Query<T>(command, param).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

The `Linq` extension method `FirstOrDefault` for `IEnumerable<T>` is not picked up presumably because of the dynamic argument but I can't understand why.

Intellisense on the method declares that it will be resolved at runtime but I don't understand why the return value is being affected by the dynamic argument as it's only an argument being passed through.

[image]

Can someone put me out of my misery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call extension methods on object of type `dynamic`.  Extension methods are a purely compile time construct.  At runtime, it will search for an instance method called `FirstOrDefault`, not find one, and therefore error out.

Your solutions are to either cast the result of `Query` to the appropriate type before calling `FirstOrDefault` on it, or to not use the extension method syntax and instead write out: `Queryable.FirstOrDefault(Query<T>(...))` which will tell the runtime binder that it's trying to bind the result of `Query` to the appropriate static method, rather than an instance method.

As for why any method accepting arguments of type `dynamic` always resolves to an expression of type `dynamic`: that's simply what the specs say to do.  The whole *point* of using `dynamic` is to defer binding of the methods until runtime, so it cannot be sure of what the value of that expression will be until runtime; to get around that, it needs to propagate the `dynamic` type.

Comment: But aren't I calling an extension method on object of type IEnumerable<T> - the dynamic just happens to be an argument?

Comment: @PhilCooper No, you're (trying to) calling an extension method on an object of type `dynamic`, as intellisense is correctly telling you.

Comment: Still does not mean that the intelisense could not be clever enough to pick this up :-)

Comment: @Steves That would be making it function incorrectly, because the expression is not in fact any type other than `dynamic`.  The type of the expression is `dynamic`.  It is *correctly* informing you of this.  It could guess at what the actual runtime type of that dynamic object might be, but *the whole point of using `dynamic` is that you don't know the types statically*.  If the types are statically know, *specify them statically*.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation, I get it now.  Looks like i'll reach out for the static method on the extension to get round this.  Now, where's that c# in depth book...

Comment: @PhilCooper linked [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382130/why-does-a-method-invocation-expression-have-type-dynamic-even-when-there-is-onl) is better than a book :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that since you called a method with `dynamic`, the return will be `dynamic` so the CLR can determine the proper method overload to use at runtime, which may cause a variation in the return type.

This means that you cannot call `.FirstOrDefault` directly, because that method doesn't exist on the class, it's an extension method (and seeing there's bot `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable` forms, an ambiguous extension). While it would be convenient, the dynamic type doesn't look up extension methods, only ones defined on the class it has at runtime.

One way to Fix this, though, is to call the Extension method as a static method:

```
return Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(Query<T>(command, param));
```

Not as elegant, but since all extension methods are static methods, this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because C# has methods overloads: the correct method to be invoked is determined by the static type of the arguments. The intellisense could be clever and find out that there is in fact only one candidate, but apparently it is not so clever.

There are decent intellisense implementations for dynamic languages like PHP (PHP tools for Visual Studio), Python and they can deal with things like that. I suppose that `dynamic` is expected to be used sparsely and in truly dynamic situations, so the authors of C# intellisense did not bother to implement such clever analysis.

Comment: Check out Eric Lippert's answer to the same question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382130/why-does-a-method-invocation-expression-have-type-dynamic-even-when-there-is-onl to understand why C# defines behavior that way (and hence intellisence behaves that way).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov nice, and the title perfectly sums it up as well 'Why does a method invocation expression have type dynamic even when there is only one possible return type?'.  'only one possible return type' led to my initial confusion.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov Eric Lippert says himself that there could be type inference, but they did choose not to implement it. Still intellisense and compiler were two different things, only now with Roslyn it is one thing. So intellisense implementors could choose to do some analysis to provide type info where possible.