# C# dynamic parameter of a function changes it return type

Tags: c#, dynamic, compilation

A simple code

```
dynamic v = "";
var a = F("");
var b = F(v);

static bool F(dynamic o) => true;
```

the type of variable a is bool, but b is dynamic instead of bool, why?

Comment: Not on .NET 3.0 or .NET 5 it isn't. What environment are you working in that thinks that `b` should be `dynamic`?

Comment: This is true on .Net Framework 4.7.2, and .Net 5.0

Comment: @user2864740 I don't know what to tell you, I'm running it in VS2017 (.net 4.7.2) and VS2019 (.net 5.0) ... "This (statement|behavior|observation) is true..."

Comment: @user2864740 I'm not following your logic ...both `bool c = b;` and `object q = b.Foo;` will *always* compile, even though `b.Foo` isn't defined, because `b` isn't resolved until runtime.

Comment: In VS2019, I do see the type say "dynamic" next to the variable `b` *in the IDE*. However, if I run this code and print `b.GetType().ToString()`, it prints System.Boolean. .NET 4.7.2.

Comment: This is a common thing where I work - we use VS2019 and Resharper. It seems like Visual Studio uses something different to perform code inspections than the regular compiler ... I have no idea. But sometimes the IDE, in certain circumstances, will show that you have errors in your code, but it will build and work just fine. And ReSharper produces its own set of warnings. Run this code, and inspect the type *while it's running*.

Comment: However, in the debugger when I set a breakpoint, `b` shows up at `dynamic (bool)` in the Locals window.

Comment: If I try to assign an integer to `b`, it compiles and runs just fine. Locals window say it's now a `dynamic (int)`. The claim is true.

Comment: @user2864740 No. Immediatly after the third line, `b = 5;`. No `var`, no redeclaration of `b`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25892550/2864740

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9381839/2864740

Comment: @Steve Ah. The behavior difference is when F is a local method vs a (static) class method. When it is a local method the compiler determines the return type to bool..

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the short answer is that once you declare a `dynamic`, the `dynamic` "behavior" (?) will continue to propagate through all future references to it until you explicitly resolve it.

It's not that the return type of `F(o)` has changed, it's that the compiler simply doesn't care anymore.

The declaration of a `dynamic` variable has disabled compile-time type-checking for all future references to *that* variable ...again, until (or unless) it's explicitly resolved.

I am looking forward to reading other explanations, however.